# Terms might be wrong: LINQ Select that will return entire intermediate object based on child subtype

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am not sure how to properly word the question, therefore I couldn't search for it. Please consider the following classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<subChild> subChildren { get; set;}
}

public class subChild
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set;}
}
```

I want a linq query to return a list of all Parents, that have at least one Child-> subchild of a certain type, but not necessarily where they ONLY have a subchild of that type.

ex:

```
Parent A
  - Child Xa
     - subchild 1a type="foo" 
     - subchild 2a type = "bar"
  - Child Ya
     - subchild 1a type="foo"
Parent B
  - Child Xb
     - subchild 1b type = "foo"
Parent C
  - Child Xc
     - subChild 1c type = "Bar"
```

This is where I got (obviously incorrect. My version compiled, case not the issue)

```
Parents.Children.SelectMany(s => s.Subchildren).where(x => x.Type="Foo").Tolist();
```

My real implementation is a bit different, and maybe my pseudo code would work the way I want it, but I want Parent A and B returned if I looked for subChild.type =  "Foo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
Parents.Where(p => p.Children.Any(
    c => c.Subchildren.Any(s => s.Type == "Foo"))).ToList();
```

Don't forget that to check for equality, you need `==` instead of `=`.

To get a list of all subchildren, you'll need something like

```
Parents.SelectMany(p => p.Children).SelectMany(c => c.Subchildren)
    .Where(s => s.Type == "Foo").ToList();
```

Comment: I missed a step from my real life, as it would be Parent -> child -> subchild -> subSubChild.
If I wanted to return all subchildren into their own list regardless of parent and children?

edit: sorry was editing and the 5 minutes timed out.

Comment: you know what? I should do the leg work from here. I can figure it out.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, discovering it yourself is probably better. You learn a lot more from that. I already posted the answer, though.